# Prove that If $f_n$ where $n>3$ is prime, then $n$ is prime for a Fibonacci series where $f_1$=$f_2$=1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

This problem came up in my conversation with a friend—not sure how basic it is, but it seems quite interesting:

Prove that if $f_n$ where $n>3$ is prime, then $n$ is prime for a Fibonacci sequence where $f_1=f_2=1.$

How can this be tackled? Thanks a bunch for any ideas.

Comment: Basically it suffices to show, that $f_n$ is a [divisibility sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_sequence) - it is shown in the link posted in the answer and also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/fibonacci-modular-results/60353#60353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer may be found at this link:

- http://www.dfcd.net/articles/fibprime.pdf