# How to find $\gcd(f_{n+1}, f_{n+2})$ by using Euclidean algorithm for the Fibonacci numbers whenever $n>1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $\gcd(f_{n+1}, f_{n+2})$ by using Euclidean algorithm for the Fibonacci numbers whenever $n>1$.  How many division algorithms are needed? (Recall that the Fibonacci sequence $(f_n)$ is defined by setting $f_1=f_2=1$ and $f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N^*$, and [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to get information about Euclidean algorithm)

Comment: $\gcd(F_{n+1},F_{n+2})=\gcd(F_{n+1},F_{n+2}-F_{n+1})=\gcd(F_{n+1},F_n)$, and then use induction...

Comment: @anon: You could consider fleshing that out to a full answer?  Given that the OP doesn't seem to be in the business of accepting answers it may not be worth your while?

Comment: Are Fibonacci numbers the "worst case" as far as efficiency of Euclid's algorithm is concerned?

Comment: @Michael: Yes. At each step, you can only subtract $F_i$ once from $F_{i+1}$, so the number of iterations needed is maximal, given the size of the two initial numbers.

Comment: @Michael: I think that the proof of that (sometime in the early 1800s, I believe) was one of the first analyses of an algorithm as well as one of the first practical applications of the Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

anon's answer:
$$ \gcd(F_{n+1},F_{n+2}) = \gcd(F_{n+1},F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}) = \gcd(F_{n+1},F_n). $$
Therefore
$$ \gcd(F_{n+1},F_n) = \gcd(F_2,F_1) = \gcd(1,1) = 1. $$
In other words, any two adjacent Fibonacci numbers are relatively prime.

Since
$$\gcd(F_n,F_{n+2}) = \gcd(F_n,F_{n+1}+F_n) = \gcd(F_n,F_{n+1}), $$
this is also true for any two Fibonacci numbers of distance $2$. Since $(F_3,F_6) = (2,8)=2$, the pattern ends here - or so you might think...

It is not difficult to prove that
$$F_{n+k+1} = F_{k+1}F_{n+1} + F_kF_n. $$
Therefore
$$ \gcd(F_{n+k+1},F_{n+1}) = \gcd(F_kF_n,F_{n+1}) = \gcd(F_k,F_{n+1}). $$
Considering what happened, we deduce
$$ (F_a,F_b) = F_{(a,b)}. $$

Comment: Here's the [complete proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/fibonacci-modular-results/60353#60353) and then some. Note that you don't need to first prove $(F_{n+1},F_n) = 1$ since it is a special case.

Comment: @anon: How do you get that gcd($F_{n+1},F_{n+2}$)=gcd($F_{n+1},F_{n+2}−F_{n+1}$)=gcd($F_n,F_{n+1}$)? I know that $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$, but how you get that $F_{n+2}=F_{n+2}−F_{n+1}=F_{n+1}$

Comment: @alvoutilla: I'm not saying $F_{n+2}=F_n$, I'm using the well-known fact that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$. If you're having trouble realizing why this works, consider thinking of $a$ and $b$ in terms of their prime factorizations (and use $\gcd(cn,cm)=c\cdot\gcd(n,m)$).

Comment: @anon: But a and b are primes in this case(because  they have not prime factorization except trivial one( a and b itself)? Where I use gcd(cn, cm) = c*gcd(n,m) and how I use it? like this gcd(ca,cb)=c gcd(a,b)= ...?

Comment: @alvoutila: You really shouldn't analyze the Euclidean algorithm without being fully familiar with basic gcd properties first. :) The identity I gave is independent of whether or not $a,b$ are primes. First let's prove it holds when $a,b$ are coprime. Suppose that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ so that they are coprime and let $d=\gcd(a,b-a)$. Since $d|a$ and $d|(b-a)$, $d$ must also divide their sum $a+(b-a)=b$ (the sum of two multiples of a number $d$ must also be a multiple of the number). But $d|a,d|b\implies d=1$ because they're coprime! (continued)

Comment: (...) Now we prove the identity in full generality: suppose $\gcd(a,b)=d$. Then $$1=(a/d,b/d)=(a/d,b/d-a/d)$$ (by our previous reasoning), so multiplying both sides by $d$ gives $\gcd(a,b)=d=(a,b-a)$, QED. If there's any part you didn't follow please let me know.

Comment: @anon: But although they are coprime( what does it mean?) they don't have prime factorization?

Comment: @alvoutila: Every whole number has a prime factorization! Two numbers are coprime if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, or in other words they share no common factor other than $1$. So $6=2\cdot3$ and $35=5\cdot7$ are coprime and they both have prime factorizations. Beyond this I'm not sure how to help you learn the relevant introductory number theory here. Were you able to follow the proof I gave? If not, you could post it as a distinct question and I think someone will make a more thorough treatment of the issue.