# If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, then $(F_m,F_n)=F_{(m,n)}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

**Edit:** The $F$'s are Fibonacci numbers.

I need an idea on how to show the following:

> If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, then $(F_m,F_n)=F_{(m,n)}$.

I believe that using the fact that $F_{m+n}=F_mF_{n+1}+F_nF_{m-1}$ could come in handy. Moreover, Euclid's algorithm may as well be needed. But I am not certain, as there may be better methods to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $f_m$, $f_n$?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what they are at the beginning.

Comment: **Hint.** $F_{kn}$ is divisible by $F_n$

Comment: This is most probably a duplicate though I can't find the link right now.

Comment: Here is one answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/fibonacci-modular-results/60353#60353

Comment: There's a step where he states that $(f_{n-m},f_m)=f_{(n-m,m)}$. Is that something that's well-known?

Comment: This is mentioned in [Wikipedia
article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Divisibility_properties),
the Wikipedia article has two references: [this
link](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20004.5.shtml) and this book:
Paulo Ribenboim, My Numbers, My Friends, Springer-Verlag 2000,
[p.9](http://books.google.com/books?id=EiYvlcimEi4C&pg=PA9).

Comment: Josué: The proof is induction on $n+m$, so this is inductive hypothesis you can assume.

Comment: @Josué sdcvvc is correct. The induction is on the sum of the indices. Thus $\rm\:(f_{n-m},f_m)=f_{\:(n-m,m)}\:$ follows by the induction, since it has smaller index sum $\rm\:(n-m)+m\: <\: n+m,\:$ by $\rm\:m>0,\:$ by hypothesis. I just edited the post to make it render better in the latest MathJax release.

Comment: I understand now. :) Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments by sdcvvc, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/12042) to an earlier question completely answers this question as well.