# Show that $5^n$ divides $F_{5^n}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

If $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number ($F_0 = 0, F_1 = 1, F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n$), show that $5^n$ divides $F_{5^n}$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136901/if-m-and-n-are-positive-integers-then-f-m-f-n-f-m-n?lq=1

Comment: Is $$(2,5^k)=5^k$$  for $k\ge1$?

Comment: In fact, $F_{5^n} \equiv 5^n \bmod 10^n$ and it seems that $5^n$ is the largest power of $5$ that divides $F_{5^n}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a+b & a \\ a & b\end{pmatrix}^5
=
\begin{pmatrix}* & c \\ c & *\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $c=5 a (a^4 + 3 a^3 b + 4 a^2 b^2 + 2 a b^3 + b^4)$. Therefore, if $5^n$ divides $a$, then $5^{n+1}$ divides $c$.

Apply this to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}^n
=
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_n\\F_n&F_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
for a proof by induction that $5^n$ divides $F_{5^n}$.

Comment: Now that we have aids like [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5Ba%2Bb,a%5D,%5Ba,b%5D%5D%5E5), we can dare compute $A^5$ just to see what comes out...

Comment: $5$ seems to be very special here: there is no obvious multiple of $k$ in $c$ for $k\ne 5$.

Comment: Interesting :-)