# if $ a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_{n}$,show that $a_{n+168}=a_{n}\pmod {13}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

as before my question:[problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010983/prove-that-there-exist-infinitely-many-postive-integers-n-such-that-a-n-is): there's one step I don't understand
$$a_{0}=0,a_{1}=a_{2}=1,a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_{n}$$
then $$a_{n+168}=a_{n}\pmod {13}$$
it is said can use calculating polynomial discriminant .But I can't Thanks

Comment: easy enough to write a program. Indeed, the sequence (taken mod 13) strats over again at $168$  with $0,1,1,2,4,7,0,$ and so on. No evident projective repeats before that

Comment: the relevant Pisano periods are listed at https://oeis.org/A046738/b046738.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea from algebraic number theory. We solve the recursion in $\overline{\mathbb F_{13}}.$ Note that our characteristic polynomial in $\mathbb F_{13}[x]$ factors as
$$x^3-x^2-x-1=(x+6)\left(x^2+6x+2\right).$$
Now fix $\alpha=-6$ with $\beta$ and $\gamma$ the roots of the quadratic. Because $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb F_{13^2}$ (they are, at worst, quadratic irrationals) we remark that it suffices to work in $\mathbb F_{13^2}$ from here on. In particular, we can solve the recursion as
$$a_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n+C\gamma^n$$
for some constants $A,B,C\in\mathbb F_{13^2}.$ To finish, we note that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb F_{13^2}^\times,$ so they have multiplicative order dividing into $\#\mathbb F_{13^2}^\times=168.$ Thus,
$$a_{n+168}=A\alpha^{n+168}+B\beta^{n+168}+C\gamma^{n+168}=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n+C\gamma^n=a_n$$
in $\mathbb F_{13^2}.$ This finishes the proof.

Comment: Why do you have overline here $\overline{\mathbb F_{13}}.$ What does it stands for?

Comment: The overline is for the [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) of $\mathbb{F}_{13}.$ The point is that we want to start in a field where all polynomials have roots so that we can write $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ without headaches; this is restricted to $\mathbb F_{13^2}$ later.