# Proving that $n|m\implies f_n|f_m$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

**Question:** Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that if $n|m$, $F_n|F_m$.

I've tried to use induction, but I don't really know where to start since there's $2$ numbers:  $n$ and $m\ \dots$ I did induction before with just $1$ number, like proving $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, that's only dealing with one number $n$, but with this I have no clue how to do it.

Can anyone give me a little hint on how to start, I don't want you to do whole problem for me but can I have some hint so I know where to start?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is $F_n$ the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number? You should use only $F$ or $f$ if they are the same thing.

Comment: From Lemma# 4 of http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/4-3/halton.pdf,   $(F_m,F_n)=F_{(m,n)}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:  Try to prove that $f_{n+m}=f_{n-1}\ f_m+f_n\ f_{m+1}$.

Then, let $m=n\times k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, prove that $f_m$ is divisible $f_n$ by induction on $k$.

Comment: I think I got it, appreciated for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the desired result without induction using [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression),
$$F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$$
where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are the roots of $x^2 + x + 1$, and the factoring identity
$$a^n - b^n = (a - b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + a^{n-3}b^2 + \cdots + ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1}).$$

Comment: Does this mean that: $$ψ = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} = φ - \frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}$$

Comment: @user477343 You should be able to answer that yourself.