# Is it possible to prove $(m\mid n \iff F_m \mid F_n)$ for a Fibonacci sequence by using only Principle of Strong Induction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I found that we can prove $(m \mid n \iff F_m \mid F_n)$ by using matrix formulation or general formula for $F_n$ ([Does $\,m\mid n$ iff $ F_m\mid F_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668999/does-m-mid-n-iff-f-m-mid-f-n)). But I'm just exposed to set theory, Peano's axioms, addition and multiplication.

I would like to know if we can prove that theorem just by using Principle of Strong Induction. I got stuck at the stage on which I have to prove that $P(k+1)$ is true.

Below is my attempt:

> Let $P(n)$ is the statement $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}(m \mid n \iff F_m \mid F_n)$.
>
> It is clear that $P(0)$ is true.
>
> Assuming that $P(k)$ is true for all $k \leq n$ i.e. $\forall k \leq n[\forall m \in \mathbb{N}(m \mid k \iff F_m \mid F_k)]$.
>
> We now have to prove $P(n+1)$ is true i.e. $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}(m \mid n+1 \iff F_m \mid F_{n+1})$.

From this point, I have no idea how to go on.

Please shed me some light! Thank you for your help ^_^

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378116/proving-that-nm-implies-f-nf-m?rq=1) is also a proof by (strong) induction.

Comment: Hi @DietrichBurde that post only solves $(m\mid n \implies F_m \mid F_n)$. I'm also interested in proving $(F_m \mid F_n \implies m\mid n)$.

Comment: No problem, this goes the same way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I tried but to no avail. Please give me some hints!

Comment: After searching our site, I found that to prove $(F_m \mid F_n \implies m\mid n)$, we must appeal to $\gcd(F_m,F_n) = F_{\gcd(m,n)}$ that involves some lemmas. Is there any simpler proof?