# Show that for Fibonacci numbers, if $m|n$ then $F_n | F_m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I've been trying to solve this problem, I realized the following: For example, for $3|6$ we have:

$$F_6=F_5+F_4=(F_4+F_3)+F_4=2F_4 + F_3$$

I realized that doing this, for $m,n$ and $m|n$ we will always get an expression such as:

$$F_n=xF_m+yF_{m+1}$$

The value of $x$ doesn't seems to matter. But if $y=F_m$ which I strongly suspect it is, then we are done because:

$$F_n=F_m(x+F_{m+1})$$

Until now, I've been unable to show that $y=F_m$ or find another way to prove this. I've been stuck for a while, can you help?

Comment: Nice observation! Yes, a result of this form is true and you can prove it by induction. If you know some modular arithmetic you can think about computing the Fibonacci sequence mod a Fibonacci number.

Comment: Read up this post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11477/fibonacci-addition-law-f-nm-f-n-1f-m-f-n-f-m1?rq=1 , and see if the pattern you are referring to is reflected or not. Some of the answers there present generalizations that you might enjoy as well, including a combinatorial proof, and a proof via matrices.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/378116/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: At the bottom of the wikipedia article on the  [matrix form of the Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form) are reported the relations

\begin{align}
 {F_m}{F_n} + {F_{m-1}}{F_{n-1}} &= F_{m+n-1},\\
 F_{m} F_{n+1} + F_{m-1} F_n &= F_{m+n}  .
\end{align}
In particular, with $m=n$,
\begin{align}
 F_{2n-1} &= F_n^2 + F_{n-1}^2\\
 F_{2n}   &= (F_{n-1}+F_{n+1})F_n\\
          &= (2F_{n-1}+F_n)F_n  .
\end{align}
Using these with $m=k\cdot n$ so that $m+n=(k+1)n$ and induction will lead you to the result.

---

**Full proof:**

We want to show that if $m\mid n$ then $F_m\mid F_n$.

Now, $m\mid n$ is equivalent to showing that $n=km\ \ k\in\mathbb{N}$. The induction will be over $k$.

Obviously $k=1$ ($m=n$) is true.

Now let's assume the statement is true for $1\leq k\leq K-1$, let's show it is true for $n=mK$ as well. By the second equality, choosing $n=(K-1)m$ we obtain

\begin{align*}
F_{n}=F_{Km}=F_{m+(K-1)m}&=F_{m}F_{(K-1)m+1}+F_{m-1}F_{(K-1)m}.
\end{align*}
But now by induction hypothesis $F_{(K-1)m}$ is divisible by $F_m$ thus $F_{(K-1)m}=F_m\cdot d$ and hence

\begin{align*}
F_{n}=F_{m}F_{(K-1)m+1}+F_{m-1}F_m\cdot d=F_m\cdot (F_{(K-1)m+1}+F_{m-1}d).
\end{align*}
which shows that $F_m\mid F_n$

Comment: I proved it using Binet's formula. But can you show me how you did it? I spent a bit of time trying to figure out how to do with that formula but couldn't do it.

Comment: Hi @BillyRubina. I've added the full proof.