# Proving Fibonacci number?

Tags: combinatorics

$f_n$ is divisible by 3 if and only if n is divisible by 4.

This seem to be true as $f_4=3$ $f_8=21$

So would I do $F_{4n}=F_{4n-1}+f_{4n-2}$

The turn n into n+1 using the induction.

$F_{4n+1}=F_{4n}+F_{4(n-1)}$ ??

Another question I have is similiar if $f_n$ divisible by 4 if and oly if n is divisible by 6.

It also seem true $f_6=8$

Would I use same method to show this.

Comment: If you wanted to do induction it would be more natural try to show that $F_{4(n+1)}$ is disvisible by three if $F_{4n}$ is divisible by three.

Comment: One or two examples tells you very little. You should be very weary of making conjectures like that. 2 is prime, so even even number is prime. 3,5,7 are all prime so every odd >1 is prime. For a less obvious example, consider $T_n$ to be the maximum number of regions formed by intersecting a circle with n lines. This is a power of 2 up until you hit 31.

Comment: You're inductive statement should be about $F_{4(n+1)}=F_{4n+4}$ by the way.

Comment: Note that if you count the Fibonacci Numbers correctly you have $f_r|f_{nr}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\overline f_n$ be the residue of the $n$th Fibonacci number modulo $3$.  We have
$$
\overline f_n = \overline f_{n-1} + \overline f_{n-2} \pmod{3}
$$
That is, the residues form a "Fibonacci sequence" modulo $3$.  We compute:
$$
\overline f_0 = 0\\
\overline f_1 = 1\\
\overline f_2 = 1+0 \equiv 1\\
\overline f_3 = 1+1 \equiv 2\\
\overline f_4 = 2+1 \equiv 0\\
\overline f_5 = 0+2 \equiv 2\\
\overline f_6 = 2+0 \equiv 2\\
\overline f_7 = 2+2 \equiv 1\\
\overline f_8 = 1+2 \equiv 0\\
\overline f_9 = 0+1 \equiv 1\\
$$
From there, the cycle repeats.  The same idea works for any divisor.  The length of this cycle for a divisor $n$ is known as the [$n$th Pisano period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period).

Comment: wouldn't mod 3 make more sense? Or did I have a brainfart?

Comment: @TimSeguine nope, the brainfart was mine.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed at the end there is also a question about divisibility by 4

Comment: yes the cycle repeats

Comment: For $6$ the residue computes to $2$? i.e.$ 1,1,2,0,2,2,1,0$

Comment: looking at it closely yes it seem so it should be 2

Comment: so can I say this would be my proof I do not have to use the induction

Comment: @MarkBennet fixed it, thank you

Comment: @FernandoMartinez this would be a way of getting around using induction.  Once you reach $0,1$ again, you know that the cycle must repeat.

Comment: I see and the method can be used if fn is divided by 3 or 4

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Or any number, for that matter. If you're a musician, you might be interested in what happens with division by $12$.

Answer (score 1):

From the Binet formula it can be shown that: $F_{n+k} = F_kF_{n+1} + F_nF_{k-1}$. Using this and induction on $m$ we can prove that $F_k$ divides $F_{mk}$ for all natural number $m$. Now letting $k=4$ we have that $3 = F_4$ divides $F_{4m}$ for all $m$.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242) for a proof of the more general result $\ \gcd(f_n,f_k) = f_{\gcd(n,k)}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: nice proof.