# Fibonacci modular results

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

5 divides every 5th Fibonacci number.
When I did this, it resulted in Lucas number series.

EXAMPLES
3,5,8,13,21    21/5= 4.25
5,8,13,21,34   34/5= 6.85 
8,13,21,34,55  55/5= 11

QUESTION 
Does "5 divides every 5th Fibonacci number" the MOST accurate, precise combination (or whatever mathematical term applies)?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/fibonacci-modular-results