# Prove the following (algebra of polynomials)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, induction, recurrence-relations, divisibility

> Let $P_1=1$ and let $P_2=n+1$ define $$P_{i+1}=\frac{P_i^2-1}{P_{i-1}}$$ Prove that if $a \mid b$ then $ P_a \mid P_b $

I am working on this problem for a while but I could use some help
here are the first 5 polynomials generated by this definition
$$ P_3=n^2+2n$$ $$ P_4=n^3+3n^2+n-1$$ $$ P_5=n^4+4n^3+3n^2-2n-1$$ $$ P_6=n^5+5n^4+6n^3-2n^2-4n$$ $$ P_7=n^6+6n^5+10n^4-9n^2-2n+1$$
Note that for instance $P_2 \mid P_6$ $$ \frac{P_6}{P_2}=n^4+4n^3+2n^2−4n $$
also $P_3 \mid P_6$ $$ \frac{P_6}{P_3}=n^3+3n^2−2 $$
Finally $(P_2\times P_3) \mid P_6$ $$ \frac{P_6}{P_2 \times P_3}=n^2+2n−2 $$
So it seems to work but who can help me prove it (I think the induction method is the most appropriate) any ideas?

Comment: $P_{i+1}=\frac{P_i^2-1}{P_{i-1}}$ is reminiscent of [Cassini's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just an idea for a start.

From given equation we can easily get this equation:$${P_{i+2}+P_{i}\over P_{i+1}} = {P_{i+1}+P_{i-1}\over P_{i}}$$ Since this is valid for all $i$ we have $$  {P_{i+1}+P_{i-1}\over P_{i}}= {P_{3}+P_{1}\over P_{2}} = n+1$$
and thus we have a linear equation:
$$ P_{i+1} = (n+1)P_{i}-P_{i-1}$$

Comment: The recurrence is reminiscent of [Fibonacci polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials).

Comment: Thank you a lot with your help I was able to prove the case that all even  indices polynomial are divisible by $P_2$

Answer (score 8):

More generally, we have

> $\qquad \gcd(P_a,P_b) = P_{\gcd(a,b)}$

a property shared by [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Divisibility_properties).

Indeed, from $P_{a+1} = (n+1)P_{a}-P_{a-1}= P_2 P_{a}-P_1 P_{a-1}$, it follows by induction that
$$
P_{a+b} = P_{b+1} P_{a}-P_b P_{a-1} \qquad (*)
$$
and so
$$
\gcd(P_{a+b}, P_b) = \gcd(P_a,P_b)= \gcd(P_{a-b},P_b) = \cdots
= \gcd(P_{a-bq},P_b)=\gcd(P_b,P_r)
$$
when $a=bq+r$, which reproduces the Euclidean algorithm.

The identity (*) is also reminiscent of
$$
F_{a+b}=F_{b+1}F_{a}+F_{b}F_{a-1}
$$
for the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388228/sequences-that-commute-with-gcd.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the problem is practically solved all is remaining is to connect the dots. Thank you very much. This is very helpful.

Comment: @Humam This is essentially a special case of the method I used in [this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60353/242) to prove that the Fibonacci numbers also satisfy this gcd property (i.e. are a strong divisibility sequence). See also the [associated question posted by lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388228/sequences-that-commute-with-gcd?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Ihf thanks for showing this process. I knew this property also holds for Fibonacci numbers, so I tried, but I could not solve immediately OP posted... now I know how to do it... thanks again!